# Circle plot error, some data offset from zero, plot inside

Tags: r, plot, geometry

I am trying to plot vanishing bearing data from pigeons in R using plot.circular from the package circular. My R packages are up to date

Currently I have two problems
1) For some reason the bearings at 270 and 90 are being plotted closer to 0 than they should. 
2) I would like to plot the data inside the circle rather than outside it

Cheers
Josh

## Example code:

```
###Data
VB<-rad(c(0,90,90,180,180,180,270,270,270,270))

##Make circular
VB<-as.circular(VB, type = 'angles',units = "radians",
        template = "none", modulo = "asis", 
        zero = pi/2, rotation = c("clock"))

##Plot 
plot.circular(VB, pch = 16, cex = 1, stack = TRUE,
     axes = FALSE, sep = 0.07, shrink = 1, bins = NULL, ticks = FALSE,
     tcl = 0.025, tcl.text = 0.125, col = NULL, tol = 0.04, uin = NULL,
     xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1), digits = 6, units = "radians",
     template = NULL, zero = pi/2, rotation = "clock", 
     main = "", sub="", xlab = "", ylab = "", 
     control.circle=circle.control())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misplaced points are apparently due to the way the bins are formed.
Try setting the `bins` parameter to some large value.

```
plot(VB, stack=TRUE, bins=360)
```

To plot inside the circle, you can use a negative value for the `sep` parameter.

```
plot(VB, stack=TRUE, bins=360, sep=-.07)
```

Comment: Did you mean `plot.circular(VB, stack=TRUE, bins=360, sep=-.07)`?

Comment: Since `VB` is an object of class `circular`, `plot` actually calls `plot.circular`: that would would be equivalent.